# How do I rig a folding door onto another rotating object that can rotate without actuating the folding door rig?

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, constraints, parent

When I rotate this door it actuates the folding of the rest by the "copy rotation" object constraints

[image]

I have the folding door controller parented to the empty that rotates the bridge.

[image]

When I rotate the bridge I want the folding door to stay closed but it starts to open

[image]

Comment: pls upload your blend file so we can find your problem

Answer (score 0):

In the *Copy Rotation* constraint, change the *Target* and *Owner* from *World Space* to *Local Space*:

[image]